# Why use a linter in a NodeJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-redux, node-modules, eslint

I am looking for a straightforward explanation of the benefit of using a linter, such as ESLint, in my NodeJS project.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Did you tried to find answer? What have you achieved so far? Can you ask more specific question?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/about/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)

Comment: The benefits in NodeJS are the same as any other programming language. It helps you write clean code that  follows popular coding styles, to reduce errors and be understandable by other programmers.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a linter in general, not just with NodeJS projects, is very similar to spell/grammar checkers that are commonly used in word processors. Just like spell/grammar checkers, you will be alerted when you make mistakes. Similar to how you can set a spell checker to add custom words to the dictionary, and you will be able to set your own preferences for what should be considered an issue, and what should be allowed.

You can also check out these articles to get a sense of what kind of practical impact you can expect from using linters, which also looks at ESlint:

- https://hackernoon.com/how-linting-and-eslint-improve-code-quality-fa83d2469efe
- https://blog.rangle.io/understanding-the-real-advantages-of-using-eslint/